# List of invisible things

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, tocloft, phantom

I need to create a list of invisible things.
For instance, in the following MWE, there is a list of examples, but it should not appear in the text.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listexamplename}{example}
\newlistof{example}{exp}{\listexamplename}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{
\refstepcounter{example}
\par\noindent\textbf{Example \theexample. #1}
\addcontentsline{exp}{example}
{\protect\numberline{}#1}\par}
\begin{document}
\example{An example}
\example{Another example}
\listofexample
\end{document}
```

[image]
The red rectangle should be removed completely from the body of text. Preferably without leaving extra space.

I have tried using `listings` package invisible caption, but if the environment is empty the caption does not show.

(This is a workaround to a more complicated issue I have - creating a manuscript with 2 TOC's in 2 languages. Therefore, the solution of `\addcontentsline{toc}{}{}` will not work)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more with what you mean by invisible list? You want to add extra space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extended, but revised, version of your MWE.

```
% loeprob.tex  SE 578105

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listexamplename}{example}
\newlistof{example}{exp}{\listexamplename}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{
\refstepcounter{example}
%\par\noindent\textbf{Example \theexample. #1}
\addcontentsline{exp}{example}
{\protect\numberline{}#1}\par}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\example{An example}
\lipsum[3-8]
\example{Another example}
\lipsum[5-6]
\listofexample
\end{document}
```

Within your definition of `\example` do not output any text except to your list of examples.

You say your real life problem is more complex as your ToC(s) is/are in two languages. You have not shown how you have done that but I assume that you can apply the same ideas to list(s) of examples.

Comment: Indeed. thanks a bunch.